# zeroclipboard - client.on function not calling

Tags: javascript

i am implementing [zeroclipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) in my website.

I've added the button and the javascript code as described at the GitHub Page. The path are ok, the JavaScript Console in Chrome doesn't show any errors.

But the **.on-function is never called.** I click on the button, and nothing happens. I've added a console.log in my js-file so i can see that it is "called".

Here is the HTML-Button:

```
<button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy me.">Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

And here my JS:

```
var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button"), {
  moviePath: "/assets/app/shared/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf"
} );

client.on( "load", function(client) {
  // alert( "movie is loaded" );

  client.on( "complete", function(client, args) {
    // `this` is the element that was clicked
    this.style.display = "none";
    alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + args.text );
  } );
} );
```

Did anybody the same problems and solved it?

EDIT: It seems like the flash-file isn't loading...[image]

Comment: just one question: when you create ZeroClipboard object is your button visible on the page and always has the same size?

Comment: I actually don't know what you mean... The button is there, same size, everytime. I reload the page, button there. Click on the button, there. Nothing changes here. EDIT: But the button isn't clickable... this must be the style.display= none?

Comment: once I was using zclip: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/ which reuses ZeroClipboard and my problem was that the flash object over my button was not created because the button was invisible (it was in a div with `display: none;` which was shown on some event). So I solved the problem by assigning this object on the moment of showing of this button.

Comment: do you run your JS code after the document is loaded?

Comment: yeah, i put it at the end of the body-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Click with the right button of the mouse to see if the flash movie was loaded in the button area. Probably the javascript is not finding your flash movie.